# How to solve ODEs by converting it to Clairaut's form through suitable substitutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Sometimes it's really confusing to find out suitable substitutions.like this one:
$(xy'-y)(x+yy')=2y'$

Which substitution should I try to put this equation in Clairaut's form?

Comment: Yes, $(xy'-y)(x+yy')=2y'$ is related to the Clairaut's equation.

Let $X=x^2$ and $Y=y^2$. This changes the ODE to :
$$(XY'-Y)(1+Y')=2Y'$$
where $Y'=\frac{dY}{dX}$. Don't confuse with $\frac{dY}{dx}$
$$Y=XY'-\frac{2Y'}{Y'+1}$$
Consequently, the usual method of solving this Clairaut's equation leads to :
$$Y=cX-\frac{2c}{c+1}$$
$$y^2=cx^2-\frac{2c}{c+1}$$

Comment: It is a pity that this question is closed. I would have written the answer in more details than in a comment. Closing it deprives others to better understand how to answer to such a problem.

Comment: @JJacquelin thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v = \sqrt{y^4 + 2 y^2 x^2 + x^4 + 4 y^2 - 4 x^2 + 4}$, so that the
equation can be written as 
$$ y' = \dfrac{y^2 - x^2  + 2 \pm v}{2 x y}$$

According to Maple, an integrating factor is 
$$ {\frac {y}{ \pm \left( {x}^{2}+{y}^{2}-2 \right) v-{x}^{4}-2\,{y}^{2}{x}^{
2}-{y}^{4}+4\,{x}^{2}-4\,{y}^{2}-4}}
$$

Comment: oh my! That is impressive.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=x^2+y^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=2x+2y\dfrac{dy}{dx}$

$\therefore\left(\dfrac{x}{2y}\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}-2x\right)-y\right)\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{y}\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}-2x\right)$

$\left(x\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}-2x\right)-2y^2\right)\dfrac{du}{dx}=4\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}-2x\right)$

$x\dfrac{du}{dx}-2x^2-2y^2=4\left(1-\dfrac{2x}{\dfrac{du}{dx}}\right)$

$x\dfrac{du}{dx}-2u=4-\dfrac{8x}{\dfrac{du}{dx}}$

$2u+4=x\dfrac{du}{dx}+\dfrac{8x}{\dfrac{du}{dx}}$

$u+2=\dfrac{x}{2}\dfrac{du}{dx}+\dfrac{4x}{\dfrac{du}{dx}}$

Let $v=x^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{du}{dv}\dfrac{dv}{dx}=2x\dfrac{du}{dv}$

$\therefore u+2=x^2\dfrac{du}{dv}+\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{du}{dv}}$

$u+2=v\dfrac{du}{dv}+\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{du}{dv}}$

Let $s=u+2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{ds}{dv}=\dfrac{du}{dv}$

$\therefore s=v\dfrac{ds}{dv}+\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{ds}{dv}}$

$s\dfrac{dv}{ds}=v+\dfrac{2}{\left(\dfrac{ds}{dv}\right)^2}$

$v=s\dfrac{dv}{ds}-2\left(\dfrac{dv}{ds}\right)^2$

Which reduces to Clairaut's ODE.

$\dfrac{dv}{ds}=s\dfrac{d^2v}{ds^2}+\dfrac{dv}{ds}-4\dfrac{dv}{ds}\dfrac{d^2v}{ds^2}$

$\dfrac{d^2v}{ds^2}\left(4\dfrac{dv}{ds}-s\right)=0$

$\therefore\begin{cases}\dfrac{d^2v}{ds^2}=0\\4\dfrac{dv}{ds}-s=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}v=as+b\\v=\dfrac{s^2}{8}+c\end{cases}$

$\therefore\begin{cases}as+b=as-2a^2\\\dfrac{s^2}{8}+c=\dfrac{s^2}{4}-\dfrac{s^2}{8}\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}b=-2a^2\\c=0\end{cases}$

$\therefore\begin{cases}v=as-2a^2\\v=\dfrac{s^2}{8}\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}x^2=au+2a-2a^2\\x^2=\dfrac{(u+2)^2}{8}\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}x^2=ax^2+ay^2+2a-2a^2\\x^2=\dfrac{(x^2+y^2+2)^2}{8}\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}(a-1)x^2+ay^2=2a^2-2a\\x^2=\dfrac{(x^2+y^2+2)^2}{8}\end{cases}$